# Very Low Quality flag on edited question. Wasted?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

The Very Low Quality flags get automatically dismissed (and become 'disputed') every time the post has been edited.

So does it make sense to flag the bad posts with this flag if:

1. the post has been edited already?
2. there is a chance the post will be edited - the question is bad, so is formatting, so someone may want to improve formatting (but it wouldn't make the question any better).

I feel the flag would be 'wasted' in that cases, so isn't it better to use other flag (which isn't auto dismissed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Very Low Quality* flags implies that the post is not salvageable through edits (I know, it's a horrible flag!). So if someone edited your post, your flag is immediately disputed (because someone did think it was salvageable via edits).

I very rarely flag as *very low quality*, but I do so when an answer is either:

- Actively harmful (promotes old APIs, contains security holes, etc), but has too many upvotes to delete.
- Truly unreadable, something that you really can't understand (language wise, not technically).

When in doubt, free-text flag for a moderator to pick it up. Do so sparingly though, 10k users can't handle free-text flags!