# Declined Flag on Low-Quality post which was radically changed

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

I had a case where I flagged a very low quality [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15233798/395659) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15259903/395659) by the same user. In the meantime a 3rd user changed the content radically to make a better quality post out of it, which is ok IMO (assuming the content is technically right).

Now what happends in this case regarding the flag weight? I get a declined flag because of "no evidence to support it" which is right after the edit, but the flag was right at the time it was set. Shouldn't a flag be *dismissed* in this case, or count as helpful considering the time it was set?

**EDIT**

I just noticed the answer I flagged was declined before the edit was done, so this explains the issue, but what I do not understand is why it was declined, this time I flagged it it had the content: **"No answer required. Just here for help.**", does this apply as an answer?

Comment: The flag *is* dismissed when a low quality post is edited. You must've flagged it just after the edit was submitted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The Edit was submitted 3 hours after i flagged it.

Comment: Then it was dismissed before the edit. See [Very Low Quality flag on edited question. Wasted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170882)

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right, i just checked the timestamp, could you plase post this as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The funny thing is that the answerflag was declined, i see it pretty obvious that this is nto an answer no? it just was: 
"No answer required. Just here for help.", are not users supposed to flag such a post?

Comment: For what it's worth, you shouldn't worry about a declined flag here or there. It's when there's a pattern of bad flags that is a problem and will, eventually, restrict your ability to flag posts at all.

Answer (score 5):

If your flag was declined, then it was handled manually by a moderator separately from the edit made.

If you had flagged the post before the edit, the edit itself would have [automatically dismissed the flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170882).

Either you flagged it first and it was declined before the edit, or you flagged it after the edit.

In this *specific* case, the question contained the answer, the OP meant to make it a self-answering question. Instead of flagging it, you could have done as j0k did and move the answer from the question post down to the answer post. Clearly, the posts were salvageable!

Comment: But am i not supposed to have some domain knowledge to know if the answer is an answer at all? how am i supposed to post an answer just like this? beside that that flag that this was not an answer is still right since it was not an answer, the OP has answered 9 questions before and should know how to post an answer we are not talking about first post here.

Comment: I would not sweat this as much, really. Sometimes you flags are declined because you missed something in the whole picture. If you normally flag correctly, the occasional dismissed flag is not going to hold you back. And just because you feel that the OP should have known better doesn't make your flag any less invalid!

Comment: I still do not see my flag as invalid, and if would have had dismissed flag it would have make sence, but declined means exactly that the flag is invalid which does not feel right that such a post can not be flagged as not an answer. whatever.

Comment: @OneMore Also recognize that your flags were incorrect, and moderators have been declining incorrect flags. "Very low quality" means "No amount of editing will make this salvageable."  The question wasn't Very Low Quality.  The answer (Before the edit) was "Not an answer".

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Is there any document defining "Very low quality"? its pretty vague and confusing when a post is a VLQ. The Question starting with "This is not really a question but rather a solution" and ending with "i hope this helps someone" is in my eyes a low quality one, at least as a question.

Comment: @OneMore: It is documented right there in the flagging dialog: *This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.* If it is not a question, than use the NARQ flag or vote to close as NARQ.

Comment: @OneMore: two seconds search here on Meta gives me: [Is the Very Low Quality flag too ambiguous?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93595)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Jeff's answer is exactly the definition i was looking for, thank you.